# Mode_rewrite adding index.php to end of url

Tags: php, apache, unix, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to apologize for not being a strong knowledge of the language, but I have a problem like that. 
I made a redirect through mode_rewrite now url is "localhost/url/url2/" apache and it redirects to
 "localhost/url/url2/index.php" how to remove from url "index.php?"

Comment: Post your .htaccess in your question.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove only index.php then put code like this in htaccess,

```
RewriteRule ^/$ http://localhost/url/url2/index.php
```

place this htaccess file where index.php is

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^url/url2/$ /url/url2/index.php [L]
```

Browser won't show index.php in the URL input.